# java.lang.IllegalStateException: You can define up to 4000 styles in a .xls workbook at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel issue

Tags: java, apache, excel, vba

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The maximum number of cell styles was exceeded. You can define up to 4000 styles in a .xls workbook    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.createCellStyle(HSSFWorkbook.java:1144) 2017-05-25 14:31:19 INFO  Main:68 - PrepareEmailMsg   at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.createCellStyle(HSSFWorkbook.java:88)     at org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellUtil.setCellStyleProperty(CellUtil.java:204)  at org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellUtil.setFont(CellUtil.java:168). How to resolve this issue. CreateCellSty is avoided in this code.?

```
for(int i=0; i<sheet.getLastRowNum();i++)           
{               
    if(sheet.getRow(i)!=null)
    {                   
        System.out.println("removed"); 
        sheet.removeRow(sheet.getRow(i)); 

    }
    else{ 
        sheet.shiftRows(2, rows, 3);    
        System.out.println("shift");        
    }           
}
```

Is this code is valid to remove data from A row of a sheet,Because after Completing of sheet this show above issue.?
Please provide Proper Suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Your problem should be coming from this code

```
    else{ 
        sheet.shiftRows(2, rows, 3);    
        System.out.println("shift");        
    }
```

Have you tried without it ?

Comment: Because I don't understand what it is supposed to do and the first part of your code should be enough to delete a row